Scraping a website on daily basis as New Match report generates
I have scraped a website where I am scraping the match report on daily basis. But for that
I have to run this code daily and then all match reports get scraped daily.
I am trying to scrape the website as the new match reports get updated only that match report
get scraped and add in previous match reports
that is todays date > yesterdays date scrape that match report and add in the data that we
scraped till yesterday.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

def write_date(output_file, date_text):
    date = date_text.strip()
    output_file.write("Date: " + date + "\n\n")
    today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return date == today

def write_content(output_file, content_text):
    output_file.write(content_text.strip() + '\n\n')

def process_link(output_file, api_url):
    page = 1
    while True:
        data = requests.get(api_url.format(page=page)).json()
        news_response = data.get("newsResponce", {})
        news_data = news_response.get("data", [])
        if not news_data:
            print("No more data available. Exiting.")
            break
        for d in news_data:
            link = 'https://www.iplt20.com/news/{d["id"]}/{d["titleUrlSegment"]}'
            r = requests.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

            try:
                data = soup.find('div', class_="vn-blogBanTitle w-100")
                date1 = data.find('span')
                if write_date(output_file, date1.text.strip()):
                     try:
                        data2 = soup.find('div', class_="container mt-4")
                        write_content(output_file, data2.text.strip())
                     except AttributeError:
                        output_file.write("Content:NA\n")
           except AttributeError:
                 output_file.write("Date:NA\n\n")
           print('Match Reports from page '+ str(page))
           break
        page += 1


def main():
    output_path = 'IPL_Output_Delta.txt'
    api_url = "https://www.iplt20.com/add-more-match-report?page={page}&type=match-reports" 
    with open(output_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        process_link(output_file, api_url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()

I have try this code to scrape daily match report of the match.
Then match report gets updated daily, I have to try scraping the website on date basis.
If todays date > yesterdays date on match report then scrape that match report.

So, what is the question?
